# Reports shareTo needs to be found

Tags: reports-folder

We have some report folders getting shared with ‘Role, Internal and Portal Subordinates’ . We are now in need of finding out all folders having this type of access. There are almost 1000 reports.

I tried in following ways,

·         SOQL query on folder object, but there was no field like shareTo.

·         Report on reports , still couldn’t find any field storing that info.

·         Then as mentioned in this, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_folder.htm , tried to retrieve using Workbench. It gave out the same XML file whatever I sent in.

Please help me with it if any success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com) you can choose the option Migration -> retrieve. There you upload a package.xml file which defines what metadata you would like to retrieve. An example that retrieves one folder is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>MyFolderNameHere</members>
        <name>Report</name>
    </types>
    <version>40.0</version>
</Package>
```

Upload that, and you get the metadata for "MyFolderNameHere". Unfortunately you have to specify each folder you would like to retrieve. Using the asterisk as a wildcard does not work for the members field here.
The resulting package will contain the sharedTo-information, just as described in the Metadata-API-description you linked to.

Comment: Thank you Florian. I was actually trying out with asterisk, that was the issue. It worked out the same way as you said. But  as i have mentioned for 1000 reports this wont help me out. Again this becomes a manual activity of clicking and opening xml for each folder. Please let me know if there is some way to filter this based on some criteria in a scenario where large number of reports exists.